# Is there a better way to get to the file from a python stack trace referencing it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

From a Python stack trace in either Output or Terminal, how to go to the file, or even better, the line where the error was raised?  Ctrl-click doesn't respond.  I have been doing ctrl-e and type the file name, but is there a faster way?

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail. Why not show your interface? What is your file path like? Are there spaces or special characters? That would make `Ctrl + Click` useless.

Comment: It was a generic question. No special characters or spaces.  Please note that I'm specifically asking about Output or Terminal where ctrl-click is not available.

Comment: So your question should be why ctrl+click doesn't work? Can you show detailed information or demonstrate it?

Comment: I mean how many ways are there to ctrl click on a file name?  when I ctrl click on a file name in **Output** or **Terminal**, the text does not become a link, and it does not take me to the file.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Of course the filename can be a link here, otherwise what do you think I'm asking you?

Comment: @JialeDu I hadn't tried in Terminal recently, but apparently now it works there.  Still not in Output.

Comment: **OUTPUT** as the output panel does not link to the file seems excusable. If you think you need this feature you can submit a feature request on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ctrl+click` in the terminal can go directly to the error line of the error file.

[image]

If you need to achieve the same effect in the **OUTPUT** panel you can submit a feature request on GitHub.